# Localized directshow device names

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, i18n, directshow, ffdshow

On my computer device list obtained by `ffmpeg` looks following:

[image]

Two devices before end named with garbage symbols. It is impossible to use these devices directly.

How to use them then?

**UPDATE**

Trying to copy/paste...

"╨б╤В╨╡╤А╨╡╨╛ ╨╝╨╕╨║╤И╨╡╤А (VIA High Definition Audio)"

Comment: Please provide the actual text instead of an image so it is searchable and easier to read.

Comment: There is no "actual text", it is a garbage. It is not surviving copy/paste.

Comment: Survived. Cheers to SO. But it does not survive if paste back to command line.

Comment: I meant in general screenshots of console outputs are not as good as copy and pasting the actual text.